# Excel: Count unique/non-duplicate values when value in another column starts with R

Tags: excel

I have a program that auto-generates reports into excel file and I need to extract amount of unique orders that have specific inventory type starting with "R" in another column. Normally it would be simple but the same order number can repeat in multiple rows, so I need to create formula that will count it without duplicates.

```
Order Number   Location
1              R-11
1              R-12
1              R-13
2              R-12
3              N-11
4              N-12

Unique orders with "R*" location: 2
```

Result of count based on above set of data should be: 2 - since there are two different order numbers that have location starting with "R".

I've tried and created following formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(B2:B7;1)="R")/COUNTIFS(B2:B7;B2:B7&"";A2:A7;A2:A7&""))
```

But it also sums unique values in "Location" column, and I get 4 instead of 2. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following (array formula, enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.)

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(LEFT(B2:B7,1)="R",A2:A7),A2:A7)>0))
```

[image]